# DV is a Fractional Response Variable. General assistance is appreciated

Tags: multiple-regression, ratio

I have the model found in the image below, where the DV 'BEVMarketshare' is a ratio bound to 0. Observations for the DV range anywhere from 6.13 e^-5 to 0.029.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Straight to the point... I've got the basics down when it comes to regression, but literature regarding my DV being a percentage leads me a little off the beaten path. Specifically, a paper entitled "Econometric Methods For Fractional Response Variables With An Application To 401 (K) Plan Participation Rates" is causing a bit of confusion. In the opening paragraphs, an argument is made against using the assumption of a beta distribution for a fractional DV saying that it "is difficult to justify
in applications where at least some portion of the sample is at the extreme values of zero or one." As my data is almost entire bound to zero, I'm guessing beta regression isn't the way to go.

Instead I have performed regression in R using the frm package, which includes the following details: *"frm uses the standard glm command to perform the estimations. Therefore, frm is essentially a convenience command, allowing estimation of several alternative fractional regression models using the same command."*

I have used this frm method with a logit link, and have sucessfully obtained a summary table. My only question is, have I gone about this the right way? I hope I've provided enough information in order to make the situation clear. If not, please let me know!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In principle, it sounds OK, but I don't think there's enough information here to say for sure.  One side remark: with the actual ratios so low, I think you could get away with using exponential regression rather than fractional logit, especially if the objective is inference rather than prediction.  But then again: if none of your responses are actually equal to zero, there's no reason you can't use beta regression, at least in principle.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Because I'm still very inexperienced with all of this, can you maybe fill me in on one thing: transformation takes place with these different methods (exponential, logit, beta, etc.), right? I've seen a study where the model said it used logit transformation for the DV, but then the model showed what looked like a simple logarithm transformation. Maybe he was doing both, or was just confused about what logit transformation actually is (like me)?! XD Thanks!

Comment: There is no transformation of the DV in any of these methods...

Comment: When would it be wise to do a logit transformation to the DV? The study I read that used this technique coincides with my thesis topic, so I'm trying to understand the rationale. I see now that I've mixed logit transformation with logit regression, but still can't really grasp either one. I don't want to get too mixed up with regression methods above my head, but I'd also hate to use the wrong method for my model. Thanks!

Comment: If you're talking about the Wooldridge paper, it doesn't transform the DV.

Comment: I'm referencing to this study by William Sierzchula: "The influence of financial incentives and other socio-economic factors
on electric vehicle adoption".

Comment: Interesting.  You have a fair question.  I have no idea why they transformed and then used OLS here, but econometricians love OLS.  Modeling the fractional response directly, as you were doing, is appropriate and avoids some drawbacks of OLS.  This link gives some more detail, and then the Baum paper referenced has still more discussion: https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/logit-transformation/

Comment: Back to your original question, I still think that what you're doing is probably legitimate, that it's hard to say for sure without knowing the details of your data and your code, and that it's important that you have a good grasp of what it is that you're doing (I'm not saying that you don't!  just be sure that you do!)

Comment: Thanks again! I've added two pictures showing samples of my data. As you can see, I have redundant data within all of my regressor data. This is because my dependent variable is on the state level, while the regressors are all on the national level. From my understanding, a normalized distribution isn't a problem. On another note, I've read more into the beta regression model and it still seems like a good choice. It seems that my coefficients will still be useful when prediction comes into play. The model also accepts heteroskedasticity. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: You'll find it instructive to plot ln $x$ and logit $x$  over your observed range from 6.13e-5  to  0.029. The two curves are essentially identical and the reason is easy to spot: logit $x$ = ln $x - $ ln $(1 - x)$ and so for $x$ very small the second term is essentially just ln $1 = 0$.  Thus although a logit link function is in principle correct for a bounded response, for your data a log link should work fine too. As with the early comments here from @The Laconic, don't transform, use generalized linear model code or equivalent specialized functions or commands.

Comment: Conventionally, a response measured on a 0 to 1 scale is called a proportion al or fractional response, not a percentage. Percentage implies (here) 0 to 100% as the range in principle.

Comment: Nick, thank you very much for your input and for catching my mistake in calling my DV a %. Can you please clarify what you mean by "plot lnx and logitx over [my] observed range". Should I take both ln and logit of my DV or to actually overlay a ln and logit curve over my range in a scatterplot? Also, I guess you're also making a case against using Beta Regression model, or? Finally, by using glm with log link, would there be any additional arguments needed in my regression code inside R? I've seen some literature showing manual tinkering to get correct results.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what difference exist between the frm package in R and just using glm. I know this relates more to R software than regression, but maybe this isn't too off-topic to ask, if someone is able to make this clear?

Comment: ln $x$ and logit $x$ are functions. So, plot those functions. That means ln $x$ and logit $x$ on the vertical axis and $x$ on the horizontal axis. I've no bias against beta regression but can't tell whether it would give similar or different results in your case. Questions about R packages are on-topic when essentially statistical but of no interest to me as I hardly ever use R and never remember details much beyond what + does.

Comment: I was able to plot both log(x) and logit(x) and saw similar curves as you mentioned. I guess I'm not sure which one would be more beneficial in my case. I've added a picture of some graphical tests with glm regression (with gaussian family log link) to check my assumptions aren't being violated. It seems that they might be, but I'm not able to discern this so well. My question now is, with which family can I run logit link in?

Comment: As the functions are essentially the same numerically for your data it follows that you can run whichever is more congenial You can use a log link so long as you realise that for some absurd combination of predictors it will predict some absurd response. Conversely, if always predicting achievable responses is important to you, use logit. Also, you should care about comparability with previous papers in your field. I am not in economics or finance and don't recognise your reference (FWIW, full details are better than just an author and title: don't expect that readers will search.)

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance, and hate to draw this out more. I guess I have just two things I'm still wondering about: (1)If I proceed with Beta Regression I'm not sure about how this all fits in with the unbiasedness assumptions.The Beta regression model literature says that it accepts heteroskedacity, which is a clear violation the homoskedacity assumption. What implications does this have for the other assumptions? I'm having trouble finding helpful information on this.(2) If I use glm, which family do I use for regression? Binomial allows for logit, though no ratios.